# how to give color in each filed in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report like this:
my records showing like this

```
Status    Location      Parkingyype  Vehiclecount
Received  blooimng      normal        1
recieved   blooimng     vip           10
parked      blooming     normal        1
deliverd    blooimng      vip           1
```

in each status i have to give separate color  only the status column ,,

my expect out put like this:how i can do this in crystal report..
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a rectangle control and set it behind your status control.

Then, depending on the value of the status control, you can set the color of the rectangle control through a formula.

Comment: sir how to create rectangle control..you mean insert BOX

Comment: Yes it's called a box. Give it a try. There is a color property available in the format menu. You can condition it and return for example a rgb() value.

Answer (score 0):

try following below steps.

1] Order your result set based on status

2] Right click on Status column in rpt file and click **Format Field...**

3] Under Border Tab, check background checkbox and click the formula check box in front of background field.

4] Add formula as per your requirement. if previous(status_coulmn) = {Status_Column} then crred else crnocolor (This formula is just for your reference)

I hope this helps!